# How to know current new object's ID in advance, before saving?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

In my ASP.NET MVC3 application (C#, SQL Server) `Product` has `ImagePath` as string type. When I save the image, I want to give product's ID value to `ImagePath`. When I create new product, I don't know what will be the current product's `ID` before `db.SaveChanges();`

```
 public ActionResult Create( Product product )
   { 
       .....
       .....//How to know ID of this product in advance?
       .....
       db.Products.AddObject( product );
       db.SaveChanges();
   }
```

I can find last item of products and increase it:

```
currentID = lastID + 1;
```

But, maybe the last ID was deleted. Result will not correct..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```
//don't save the image yet, or save it in a temporary location
db.Products.AddObject( product );
db.SaveChanges();
product.ImagePath = //path including product.Id
//save or move image to product.ImagePath
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't be done, what will you do, if two users at same time try to create products? Add images and then set relation with product.

Comment: Product can have maximum 5 images. And in every day product's images are saving to same folder. Tomorrow, to other folder. Customer want to watch that folder and delete any image he want. He want that I set relation between product and its images

Comment: @Mores Alternatively you can send data with ajax, receive id and give ability for image uploading.